# Jquery length of matched query

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I write both of these without using .each() and only using JQuery Selectors?

```
var xxxx = 0;
$('.clonedInput').each(function(index) {
    if($(this).children().filter(':checked').length == 2)
    xxxx++;
});


var num_normal_foods = 0;
$('[id^="amount_"]').each(function(index) {
    if($(this).val() == '30.00')
    num_normal_foods++;
});
```

Comment: So what's so bad about using `.each()` ? No matter how your write this code, you're performing an implicit loop somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets take this one step at a time.

You started with:

```
var xxxx = 0;
$('.clonedInput').each(function(index) {
    if($(this).children().filter(':checked').length == 2)
    xxxx++;
});
```

To me this looks like you're simply trying to [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) a collection of `.clonedInput` elements and find out how many match the filter:

```
var xxxx;
function hasTwoCheckedChildren(i) {
    return $(this).children(':checked').length == 2;
}
xxxx = $('.clonedInput').filter(hasTwoCheckedChildren).length;
```

Followed by:

```
var num_normal_foods = 0;
$('[id^="amount_"]').each(function(index) {
    if($(this).val() == '30.00')
    num_normal_foods++;
});
```

Again, this looks like a filtering function to me:

```
var num_normal_foods;
function valueIsThirty(i) {
    return +$(this).val() === 30;
}
num_normal_foods = $('[id^="amount_"]').filter(valueIsThirty).length;
```

---

In the end, what matters is that the code does what you intend it to do. If the code you wrote with `.each` does what you want it to, then there's no need to change it. Behind-the-scenes `filter` uses `each` anyway.

Comment: I'd use `+$(this).val() === 30` for that last one

Comment: @Alnitak, that works too, but `val()` returns a string, and we really only care if that's equal to `'30'` anyway. I suppose if you want to be certain that things like `'0x1E'` get correctly counted as equal to `30` then your method is more resilient.

Comment: actually I was more concerned about `30.00`, per the OP's current code.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery selections have a .length property:

```
var len = $('.clonedInput :checked').length;
var len2 = $('[id^="amount_"][value="30.00"]').length;
```

the first query returns all of the checked children of any .clonedInput class, then counts them.

the second query finds all of the id's that begin with amount_ and have a value of "30.00". (property queries can be chained like that [][])

**EDIT:**  to satisfy  @Blazemonger

to get the value of any type of element (value works on some), use this:

```
var len2 = $('[id^="amount_"]').filter(function() {
  return $(this).val() == "30.00";
}).length;
```

**Double EDIT** because i'm useless

```
var len = $('.clonedInput').filter(function(){
   return $(this).children(':checked').length == 2;
}).length;
```

Comment: the "value" attribute is not necessarily the same as `.val()`.

Comment: @Blazemonger What do you mean

Comment: Both of those selectors are wrong. The first one because the original function is filtering out `.clonedInput` elements that have ***exactly 2*** checked children, not simply *any* checked descendants. The second one's wrong because `.val()` doesn't necessarily get the `[value]` attribute, as is the case with `<textarea>` and `<select>` elements.

Comment: you still haven't fixed the first query - he wants the number of `.clonedInputs` that have exactly two `:checked` children - not just the total number of _all_ `:checked` children.

Comment: @zzzzBov Ohh that's right, i was wrong about the first one also. forgive me.

Comment: fixed. now if you excuse me, i'm going to go cry in shame in the corner.